# Why do we shift by three in RISC-V loops?

Tags: assembly, risc-v

In [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F-lwtStKeak&list=PL-Mfq5QS-s8iUJpNzCOtQKRfpswCrPbiW&index=4&ab_channel=AmirH.Ashouri) youtube video, the instructor explained some basic code in RISC-V assembly, but i didn't understand why in the first line, he is shifting i by 3. Why do we have to multiply it by 8??

I feel like it has something to do with the fact that LOAD IMMEDIATE operations can load values up to 12 bits only, but I couldn't make the connection.

[image]

Comment: What is save? Is it by any chance an array of 8 byte values? in which case the shift is about converting the index (which increments by 1 per array item), into an address offset (which increments by the size of the array item per item)

Answer (score 2):

The [ld](https://msyksphinz-self.github.io/riscv-isadoc/html/rv64i.html#ld) instruction…

> Loads a 64-bit value from memory into register rd for RV64I

It's then safe to say that the type of `save[i]` is 8 bytes large, something like this:

```
uint64_t save[10] = { 1, 2, 3, ... };
...
while (save[i] == k) i += 1;
```

In C, `save[i]` addresses the *object* so the compiler must adjust for its size.

Comment: `ld` is "load doubleword", aka "load 64 bits from memory", so `save` is *definitely* an array of 64-bit values.

Comment: @JonathanS. Thanks, I know nothing about RISC-V but I found a reference and added a link to it.